# variable referenced before assignment error despite it being referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function, operating-system, text-files

This is most likely an error on my part due to the lack of skills when coming to coding but I came across something I never had before, and that was when using functions and having them refer to other functions, the variables can be muddled up and produce an error. I need someone to help break down what is happening. Please help and thank you in advance

```
import os

def main():
  if os.path.exists("Text.txt")==True:
    with open("Text.txt", "r") as f:
      li=[]
      for lines in f:
        li.append(eval(lines))
    for i in range(0, len(li)):
      if i == 0:
        a = li[i]
      elif i == 1:
        b = li[i]
      elif i == 2:
        c = li[i]
      elif i == 3:
        d = li[i]
      else:
        pass
  else:
    open("Text.txt", "w").close
    a=[1]
    b=[2]
    c=[3]
    d=[4]
  menu(a, b, c, d)
def menu(a, b, c, d):
  print(a, b, c, d)

main()
```

when i run the code an error appears that says:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 30, in     main()  File "main.py", line 26, in main
    menu(a, b, c, d)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full error traceback

Comment: Aside: you don't need `==True` or the entire clause of `elif` (simply use `else` instead).

Comment: @G.Anderson done

Comment: What's the content of `Text.txt`? Your code implicitly assumes it has 4 lines, but given the error says that `c` isn't defined then it seems it actually only has two. [By the way, there are vastly better ways of writing this logic.]

Comment: Take `a` for example. If `os.path.exists("Text.txt")` returns `True`, but the file is empty, `a` is never assigned.

Comment: URGENT:  For some reason, it looks as if the code is jumping to the last function and producing an error from that despite running the code and eventually getting a variable

Answer (score 1):

```
    import os


def main():
    a, b, c, d = None,None,None, None # Use None or any other data type you are using
    if os.path.exists("Text.txt"):
        with open("Text.txt", "r") as f:
            li = []
            for lines in f:
                li.append(eval(lines))

        for i in range(0, len(li)):
            if i == 0:
                a = li[i]
            elif i == 1:
                b = li[i]
            elif i == 2:
                c = li[i]
            elif i == 3:
                d = li[i]
            else:
                pass
    else:
        open("Text.txt", "w").close
        a = [1]
        b = [2]
        c = [3]
        d = [4]
    menu(a, b, c, d)


def menu(a, b, c, d):
    print(a, b, c, d)

main()
```

Define a, b, c and d before and should fix the issue.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should be before the if. I edited, check now

Comment: Works to me, did you define like I put on the example?

Answer (score 1):

variable c is not always defined in your code.

Check for example with something like:

```
def main():
  c=None
  ...
  if ...
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In the "else" block you are opening the "Text.txt" with write mode but nothing is saving on it. So, if you try to execute the script again, it will enter in the "if" block, open the file and read nothing. In instance, the code is not entering in the "for" loop and, in consequence, the variable can not be instantiated, throwing the error. Your are saying the error is about the "c" variable, this can be due to you wrote something in the text file but less than 3 lines.

I tried your code and obtained this when i write two lines in the text file:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-275a763cfa3b> in <module>()
     28     print(a, b, c, d)
     29 
---> 30 main()

<ipython-input-41-275a763cfa3b> in main()
     24         c=[3]
     25         d=[4]
---> 26     menu(a, b, c, d)
     27 def menu(a, b, c, d):
     28     print(a, b, c, d)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment
```